# Custom Choropleth Labels in Geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

I am attempting to make a choropleth plot in `geopandas`. Because of the large number of objects and a highly skewed distribution, I am binning into quantiles using the built in `mapclassify` support. It is working great, except the labels for the resulting legend are terrible.

As a test case, I have produced the following:

[image]

Using the following code:

```
import geopandas as gp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

world = gp.read_file(gp.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
world.plot(ax=ax,column='pop_est',
           cmap='OrRd',
           scheme='quantiles',
           legend=True,
           legend_kwds=dict(loc='upper right',
                            bbox_to_anchor=(1.5, .9),
                            fontsize='small',
                            title="Legend",
                            frameon=False)
           )
ax.axis('off')
```

I want at a minimum to be able to have fully custom labels for the legend, for example:

- <2.35mil
- 2.36mil<6mil,
- ...
- >38mil

However, the ideal case would be to have a continuous blocked colorbar with custom labels, for example, like the following US map (which I did not produce):

[image]

Comment: Check out `ax.get_legend_handles_labels`

Comment: @QuangHoang Could you be a little more specific? I believe this is a little more nuanced than plotting lines with labels. Calling that method on ax yields an empty touple.

Comment: Maybe see [how-do-i-plot-a-differences-map-using-geopandas-and-mapclassify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55679885/how-do-i-plot-a-differences-map-using-geopandas-and-mapclassify)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest This is very very close, but I'm still struggling here in this context.

Comment: What's the difference? What do you need that the other solution doesn't provide? (It event uses the same data, it seems?!)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest there is no customization of labels in that example which is the main concern.

Comment: [colorbar_tick_labelling_demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/colorbar_tick_labelling_demo.html)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Ok. Now we we very close. I just can't quite connect the dots here since the goal is to use the pre-defined quantiles to create the bins and I think I am getting confused how to incorporate a `cmap` with discrete bins and custom labels. If it is so straightforward, then it would be nice to have a simple solution, then I can also mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: The bins are defined by the `bounds` variable in the linked answer. The ticks would probably best reside in the middle of those bins. I don't consider it necessary to provide that same answer here again.

Answer (score 1):

It was not directly obvious from the comments how to do this. The following, bit verbose piece of code produce something with a custom legend:

```
import geopandas as gp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def update_custom_legend_labels(ax, new_labels):
    current_legend = ax.get_legend()
    for ix_current_label, txt_current_label in enumerate(current_legend.texts):    
        for ix_new_label, txt_new_label in new_labels.items():        
            if ix_current_label == ix_new_label:
                # print(f'current: {ix_current_label, txt_current_label}')
                # print(f'new: {ix_new_label, txt_new_label}')
                txt_current_label.set_text(txt_new_label)
                # print(f'update: {txt_current_label}')

world = gp.read_file(gp.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
world.plot(ax=ax,
           column='pop_est',
           cmap='OrRd',
           scheme='quantiles',
           legend=True,
           legend_kwds=dict(loc='upper right',
                            bbox_to_anchor=(1.5, .9),
                            fontsize='small',
                            title="Legend",
                            frameon=False, fmt="{:.0f}")
           )

current_labels = [t.get_text() for t in ax.get_legend().get_texts()]

no_labels = len(current_labels)
new_labels = []
for ix, val in enumerate(current_labels):    
    if ix == 0:  # first item
        val = '<' + val.split(',')[0]
    elif no_labels == ix + 1:  # last item
        val = '>' + val.split(',')[0]        
    else:  # remaining items
        val = val.replace(',', ' -')            
    new_labels.append((ix,val))
new_labels = dict(new_labels)    

update_custom_legend_labels(ax, new_labels)
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.show()
```

[image]